# New to Zend framework, how can I translate my php 'result' (Huge Array) to something workable like a table?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend-framework

```
array(556) { ["A1"]=> string(9) "Timestamp" ["B1"]=> string(17) "Untitled Question" ["C1"]=> string(17) "Sample Question 1" ["D4"]=> string(23) "Project Scheduling 2010" ["AJ4"]=> string(4) "2011" ["D5"]=> string(13) "Send Feedback" ["J5"]=> string(4) "JUNE" ["N5"]=> string(3) "JUL"
```

^ - etc..is the array I'm receiving after successfully connecting to my google spreadsheet and getting a feed for 'all cells'. The problem is that I'm a novice and don't know how to take this array as a data source to convert it into something manageable like gridview/some html table equivalent.

What should I do with this array if I basically want to just read it with javascript/css to create a clone that I can work with [by that I mean it looks like a spreadsheet, in the future with some adjustments I'll be able to edit functionality - clicking a cell will open an accordian modal with information from another page etc etc...stuff Google Spreadsheets won't let me code into its interface - I want control here].

If my question is too vague/verbose I'll try to reword it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class My_View_Helper_GDataTable extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function gDataTable($data)
    {
        $firstLetter = intval('A');
        $numCols = $this->_getNumCols($data);
        $res = '<table>';
        for ($j = 1; $j <= $numRows; $j++) {
            $res .= '<tr>';
            for ($i = $firstLEtter; $i <= $firstLetter+$numCols; $i++) {
                $res .= '<td>' . $data[$i.$j] . '</td>';
            }
            $res .= '</tr>';
        }
        $res .= '</table>';  
        return $res;          
    }

    protected function _getNumCols($data)
    {
        /*  
            to be implemented
            not sure how exactly can you do it
            zend gdata should offer some method for this
        */
    }
}
```

Then in view:

```
//somewhere in view init
$view->addHelperPath('some/path', 'My_View_Helper');
//in your view
$this->gDataTable($dataFromZendGdata);
```

Comment: Sorry Tomáš, It looks like I don't understand $numCols = getSomehow(); or how to incorporate this function into my current reader file. I've pasted both attempts at reading the spreadsheet as an array here: http://pastebin.ca/2001092 [if we can work from that point I'll probably understand it a lot better, thank you in advance]

Comment: I'm also new to the framework itself so be gentle, if I turned that into a 'view helper' I still don't see how I can get the maximum number of rows :(. Ideally, once I have an html grid that represents the google spreadsheet cell by cell in a table - I can start playing with the page indefinitely. Can't seem to explode this array into a table cell-by-cell unfortunately using this example.

Comment: Been looking into this today and I really just don't get how to setup a view helper with this. I understand that Zend likes templating output with them but no idea how to use your example in that context. Any help would be appreciated[Seems odd how its so easy to grab rows/cells/arrays but no way of converting it to html].

Comment: I updated the solution. Hope it helps. About hte number of cols - i have no idea how you can get it.

Comment: One awful solution is to iterate through the array using double foreach (one for numbers and one for letters) and you will keep only the biggest of each and test is using isset($data[$letter.$number]); when you have the maximal - you store it's letter = max letter and number = max number :)